# Moderators can delete comments on any post but not undelete them prior to signing the moderator agreement

Tags: bug, status-review, comments, moderator-tools, deleted-comments

Is it expected behavior that an elected (but before accepting the agreement) moderator can delete any comment on the post, but unable to undelete them? Even for my own comments I got the error:

> An error occurred while trying to undelete

If it's expected what's the background for this?

Comment: This really is an edge case though. Mods are _required_ to accept the agreement and cannot be moderators if they have not. It's just that this isn't automated, so you end up with odd cases like this in the meantime. Is it really worth spending dev time on something like this?

Comment: @terdon this particular issue probably not. But it could potentially indicate an area where the permissions checks are flawed. Not particularly likely, but might be worth a quick look to make sure there is nothing more wrong with the checks there

Comment: @MadScientist Not to mention cases where the team makes changes to the moderator agreement and requires all current mods to sign again - that's what happened with the prior changes, with mods who didn't sign by the deadline having their accounts placed in the same status as a new moderator who hasn't signed any agreement yet. This was so they could impose a deadline without having to take mods who refused to sign through a removal process - the three choices were to either sign the agreement, resign as a moderator, or be procedurally removed for inactivity.

Comment: @V2Blast Suggestion: if you change a moderator-only tag and also add the tag [tag:status-review], please be sure to change the title so it corresponds to the new tag. I know titles are important in the internal review queue, and the previous title was still phrasing it as a support question, so it may not be noticed as a bug by other staff. I've since edited the title so it's clearer it's a bug report, so it'd be nice if you updated that in the internal ticket.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I remember Catija saying elsewhere that title edits on status-review'd posts will create a whole new ticket. I'd have to dig *really* hard to find that, though, as it was a comment and has probably since been deleted.

Comment: @Spevacus She was referring to the fact that edits to posts that were given that tag before the escalation process was introduced in March 2020 will cause tickets to be created for items that didn't initially have tickets for them. On the other hand, there have been comments from V2Blast that the internal ticket's title is based on whatever the title of the question is at the time it's tagged, and that matters a lot (for instance, a site asked for both unregistered questions and answers to be blocked but the title only mentioned questions so that's what was rolled out initially).

Comment: Regardless of the context, @Spevacus is still correct. Jira checks the title of the question and if it gets edited, we get a new ticket. It's not a huge issue because it's easy enough to delete it but there are cases where people edited the title several times and we got 4-5 different tickets.

Comment: @Catija Oooohhh, so we can have fun spamming y'all with tickets. :) Does it create the ticket immediately, only after the grace period expires, or as a task run every N minutes?? If it creates the ticket immediately, that could be a lot of tickets using grace period edits. :)

Comment: @Makyen I think it only checks the sites every five minutes or so. :P